# Can I answer an unclear question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Regarding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667418/string-does-not-contain-definition-of-contains), I thought the question was unclear since the question doesn't have necessary information and is a little bit confusing. But later it got answered by a high reputation user. Please have a look at my [comments under the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667418/string-does-not-contain-definition-of-contains/45667470?noredirect=1#comment78292416_45667470). I have voted the question to close, and down voted, Later I saw one upvote for the same question and doesn't see any support for my close votes

My questions:

- Was that the correct decision to answer the question?
- Were my comments correct?

Comment: About your comments: For me as a non-native speaker, the first comment sounds rather harsh. You should (imho) judge each answer separately and write comments about the answer, not against the person answering it.

Comment: @BDL: Yep you are correct, But actually I have noted the same issues with few previous posts of the same user, And that's why mentioned like that. Anyway thank you for the advise

Comment: It is not an unclear question, the compile error message is very clear.  The only thing unclear is what kind of code generated the message.  Well, that's why he asked the question, he doesn't know.  Ideally there is repro code, but that would be chicken-and-egg and he'd never asked it, the rubber ducky would have done its job.  The posted answer was not helpful.  "Look at the message and figure it out" is not helpful so you can't post it.  I seriously doubt the linked dup is helpful.  Notable how this is the meat-and-potatoes of a Q+A site.  I posted a guess, but doubtful we'll ever hear back.

Answer (score 14):

It is a bit unclear, yes so that close reason applies. Googling the title alone gave me several duplicates so I don't understand why you didn't use your gold badge holder dupe hammer privilege.

There is no rule that strictly forbids answering a question that is unclear to you but clear enough for others. You can of course leave a comment on the answer to explain your down vote (which you obviously forgot to cast) but beyond that all you can do is pester the OP into submission with comments until they admit they were wrong and will not answer such question again, ever.

The answer doesn't bring much new insight above what I've found in the other questions and answers on this particular error message. It might be useful for the OP.

When the duplicate chain is in place it is up to the community to decide if this is a good enough dupe to keep around. If not you can cast a delete vote to get rid of the question. That takes care of the answer as well.